# There is an error when trying to order in python-django

Tags: python, django, view

Whenever I try to order something, I keep getting this error.

[image]

Here is my views.py:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    session = request.session
    cart = session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    if cart:
        del session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
else:
    customer = request.user.customer
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
        customer=customer, complete=False)

    order_products = OrderProduct.objects.filter(order=order)
    if order_products:
        order_product = order_products[0]
    else:
        order_product = OrderProduct.objects.create(order=order)

    order.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Заказ успешно оформлен. Проверьте свою электронную почту!!!')
    session = request.session
    del session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]

return redirect('product_list')
```

Please can anyone help me to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key doesn't exist in your session, so check if it is there before deleting

```
if settings.CART_SESSION_ID in session:
    del session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
```

Comment: I am not getting errors anymore after this, but it was supposed to delete products in the cart after ordering. Now there are still products in the cart after the order. can you help to fix this?